# Error in java with selenium : Expected [object Undefined]

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

> I don't understand why I get the error Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string

Here is the script java LoginToGmail.java

```
WebDriver driver;
driver =new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.navigate().to("http://www.facebook.com");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement act= driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
act.sendKeys("rupali9392@gmail.com");
```

full stack error is :

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a
string Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:00:17 -0800'
Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\SHEKHAR\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozpr‌​ofile.mipot0y6Nzs5,
rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, 
pageLoadStrategy=normal ,platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false,
acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=53.0, platformVersion=6.1, moz:processID=5892,
browserName=firefox, platformName=windows_nt}]
```

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:00:17 -0800'

Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\SHEKHAR\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.mipot0y6Nzs5, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=53.0, platformVersion=6.1, moz:processID=5892, browserName=firefox, platformName=windows_nt}]

Comment: I aim simply trying to open the browser and and navigate to facebook

Comment: This is due to a bug in Mozilla's `geckodriver`. A fix is forthcoming, but no release date is announced.

Comment: I cannot go with Mozilla and Selenium 3.0?? Please help me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To work with Selenium 3.x, Mozila Firefox 52.x you need to download the latest gecko driver from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and provide the absolute path of gecko driver as follows:

```
//Mozila Firefox
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http:\\gmail.com");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("your_id");
```