# Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string (IndexOutOfBounds)

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm facing an issue for sendkeys in Firefox, it is throwing an exception "Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string (IndexOutOfBounds)".

I added the path of geckodriver to system variables so not sending path in the code.

Firefox Driver:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/csv, text/csv, text/plain,application/octet-stream doc xls pdf txt");
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);
profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", true);
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
profile.SetPreference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
profile.SetPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
_driverInstance = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

StackTrace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string (IndexOutOfBounds)
Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.InternalExecute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.SendKeys(String text)
at LoginPage.set_forgotPwdEmail(String value)
```

Every testcase that has SendKeys() throws this error.

I read some questions in SO and came to know that it is the issue with Firefox. Is there a work around in the meanwhile until it is fixed.

Firefox version: 53.0
GeckoDriver :geckodriver-v0.15.0-win64
Selinium version: 3.3.0

Comment: The "workaround" is to use geckodriver 0.16, which is now available.

Comment: @JimEvans Thanks for the reply. I verified for the latest Gecko on Friday, by then it's still V 0.15. Didn't verify it today. Thanks again. I'll try with the latest version.

Comment: @JimEvans Thank you it worked. We need to update selenium to 3.4 to support Gecko v 0.16. Once both are updated no issues. Thanks again.

Comment: There is an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43474586/986720 (yes, you need to update the geckodriver).

Answer (score 1):

1. Update Selenium to version 3.4
2. Update GeckoDriver to version 16 or newer

If issue will be displayed change driver from 64 bit to 32 bit

Answer (score -1):

I used JavaScript to enter value where Send Keys didn't work for me:
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value = 'Test'", password);

Comment: password is a WebElement

Comment: Did you try updating driver?

Answer (score -3):

Try using 
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

For example:

```
IWebElement Password = driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtPassword"));
 Password.SendKeys("pass");
 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
 Password.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

Comment: How is this supposed to help?

Comment: in my case when i uses sleep or wait then it executed. sometimes it shows "Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string (IndexOutOfBounds)". error when net speed too slow or the application is not responding.